# How to debug a DLL from another DLL in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have 3 projects (A, B and C) A is in C#, B and C are in C++.
A references B as a dll and B references C as a dll.
A is the main project.
I can debug B attaching process in the Debug menu, but I can't debug C.

I unchecked the "Enable Just My Code" option: menu Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> Enable Just My Code.

But it seems that something is missing. I am sure that code of C is executing since I have coded some logging.

I can't change the architecture of the projects, like moving code of C to B or something like that.

Comment: Is this something that isn't testable through unit testing?

Comment: Are you sure the newest build of DLL C is loaded from the expected place? Use Process Monitor to check. If e.g. a release build of DLL C is loaded from somewhere else, it can't find the symbols. `Copy local` may help

Comment: The code for unit testing is not done. 
@Thomas I checked and all the projects are Copy local = true. 
I think I have a clue. Somebody told me to type F11 in a place where the projects A and C connect, and see what happens. I am doing that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I changed too these settings:
Debugging->Options->Check both Load DLL exports and Enable RPC Debugging.
When Attaching Process, before attach a process click Select and enabled only T-SQL, Managed 4.0 and x86 and finally it worked